# Why [NSURL URLWithString:] escapes some characters in url string and doesn't for other characters?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I found that [NSURL URLWithString:] method escapes some characters in url string passed to it automatically. e.g. it escapes brackets. But url string contains other non-legal url characters such as < and > causes the method return nil

```
[[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.bar/?key[]=value[]"] absoluteString]
```

returns the same result with

```
[@"http://foo.bar/?key[]=value[]" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

while,

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.bar/?key[]=value[]<>"] returns nil, not a url with an escaped string.
```

what exactly happens during initiating NSURL instance? why it escapes (maybe) only brackets?

Comment: Are you still getting nil when you do `NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://foo.bar/?key[]=value[]<>" stringByAddingPercentExcapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]];` ?

Answer (score 4):

[`NSUrl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [`URLWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB) will not escape the string as stated by the docs:

> This method expects URLString to contain any necessary percent escape
>   codes, which are ‘:’, ‘/’, ‘%’, ‘#’, ‘;’, and ‘@’. Note that ‘%’
>   escapes are translated via UTF-8

However, you should be able to do the following using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`:

```
NSString *myString = @"http://foo.bar/?key[]=value[]<>";
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding makes makes things easy except it doesn't escape ampersand. However what I'm concerned is not that URLWithString returns nil when I pass not-escaped string but that URLWithString ESCAPES brackets automatically. I think it should NOT escape any characters =(